# Porting MATLAB functions to Scilab. How do I use symbolic?

Tags: python, matlab, porting, scilab, sympy

I'm porting some [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) functions to [Scilab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab). The cool thing is that there is a [conversion toolbox](http://ralyx.inria.fr/2004/Raweb/scilab/uid96.html) that make things very easy.

The problem is I did not find the counterpart to the **syms** function, and the symbolic toolbox in general. (I'd like a port of the *Control System Toolbox* too, amd I'm still searching for some functions I'd may need).

The only thing about symbolic toolbox I've found is [this](http://www.cert.fr/dcsd/idco/perso/Magni/s_sym/doc/index.html), but it was a little trcky and not so easy (actually I was not able to set up it correctly in 30 minutes, and I gave up for now. I'm going to try later), and it needs Maxima to be installed. Does anyone know anything about that?

Scilab is not exactly a must. The project aims to give a more *free* and *open source* alternative to MATLAB. I saw there is [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) for [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), and I just could use it with [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/), but I'd lost the [conversion toolbox](http://ralyx.inria.fr/2004/Raweb/scilab/uid96.html) thing :\

That said, what should be better? Get SciLab and Maxima work together or move to Python & co.? This is the start of the project, so the earlier I choose this, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Bye MATLAB, hello Python, thanks Sage](http://vnoel.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/bye-matlab-hello-python-thanks-sage/) for a first-hand experience of migrating from [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Not to discourage your project, but if you just want a *free* and *open source* alternative to [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), have you looked at the [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) project? Contributing there might be more productive than building your own MATLAB alternative.

If your project requires the functionality of MATLAB's Symbolic then take a look at

- http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?CategorySymbolic

From my quick Google search I didn't find anything comparable to MATLAB's Simulink.

Also, Python and SciPy do have most of the functionality of MATLAB, and I guess Scilab's conversion utility would be useful in porting your own M-Files into Scilab code.

Your question seems to imply you want to port over MATLAB Toolboxes

> The only thing about symbolic toolbox I've found is this...

I hope I am just misinterpreting you. If you are then there might be licensing issues if you were to distribute your system because the MATLAB Toolbox. Just a thought. But perhaps you wish to port your MATLAB code to, so that it doesn't not have the MATLAB dependency.

#### Update

For Control System functionality Octave, I just found that Octave does have a toolbox, see:

- [Octave Control Systems Toolbox](http://www.obihiro.ac.jp/~suzukim/masuda/octave/html/octave_125.html)

Which has some of the functionality of Simulink, but it doesn't seem to have the graphical interface for building block diagrams.

Comment: I'll look at Octave. I've to port some M-Files, unfortunately they use 2 toolboxes (Control System Toolbox and the symbolic one). The most needed one is the symbolic. I did not understand what you said about licensing issues (maybe it is my English's fault). Can you explain me that?

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood your question.  From your question it sounded like you wanted to port Matlab toolboxes to Scilab and distribute them.  I think this would be inviolation of Matlab's License.

Comment: I'm not porting a toolbox, I'm porting some M-Files I wrote. They use functions from two toolboxes and I'm looking their counter part.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your question. Anyway, hope you find what you need.